# UITableView header and footer height not corresponding with Storyboard layout

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, interface-builder

In my Storyboard, I've added a header and a footer view. I've set the frame property in the properties panel, but somehow the height of these views becomes way taller when I run the application in the simulator or on the device... What gives?

**Layout in Interface Builder (Pink background for visibility)**

[image]

**Corresponding view in iOS simulator (iPhone 6s)**

[image]

Comment: Give your components a maximum height value constraint.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably that you are using a bottom constraint to its parentView for the footer (the pink one) and as the UITableView renders, it ends up filling up the empty space between the bottom of the table view and the bottom of its parent. Instead of having a bottom constraint, try adding a max-height constraint to it.